# Different instances of an object with a Session or Application scope in JEE7

Tags: java, java-ee-7, inject, apache-tomee

I would like to inject different instances of the same object (with Session or Appplication Scope).

I would like to have two different instances of the car counter (one for the red ones and one for the green ones).
Instead it creates two references to the same object.

How can I solve the problem ? (keeping the counter with Application Scope in a service rest with session Scope).

**RestSession**

```
@Path("/api/session")
@SessionScoped   
public class RestSession implements Serializable {

    @Inject @Contatori
    private IContatore countRedCar;

    @Inject @Contatori
    private IContatore countGreenCar;   

    @Produces("application/json")
    @GET
    @Path("/red")
    public ResultDTO countRed() {
        countRedCar.conta();
        return new ResultDTO(countRedCar.getCount(),countGreenCar.getCount());
    }

    @Produces("application/json")
    @GET
    @Path("/green")
    public ResultDTO countGreen() {

        countGreenCar.conta();

        return new ResultDTO(countRedCar.getCount(),countGreenCar.getCount());
    }
}
```

**Conta**

```
package it.paolo.javaee.util;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
@Contatori
public class Conta implements IContatore{

    private int count;

    public Conta() {
        count=0;
    }

    public int conta() {
        return count+=1;
    }

    public void setCount(int i) {
        count=i;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

**IContatore**

```
package it.paolo.javaee.util;

import java.io.Serializable;

public interface IContatore extends Serializable {

    public int conta();

    public void setCount(int i);

    public int getCount();

}
```

**@interface Contatori3**

```
package it.paolo.javaee.util;

import javax.inject.Qualifier;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;


@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Contatori3 {
}
```

Comment: Is there possibly a typo: `@Contatori` and `@interface Contatori3`

Comment: Both your injections use the same qualifier `@Contatori`, hence giving you the same instance

Comment: it's a writing error

Answer (score 0):

As Felks comment says with this approach you might need two separate qualifier annotations and two producing beans/methods for your counters. But as it seems that you have only one bean implementation for `Conta` maybe it is not necessarily the best approach?

Maybe you could try something like this:

- change your class `Conta` to just a normal class so no bean
- create a new `@ApplicationScoped` bean to hold all the possible `Contas`

This new bean could be like:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Getter
public class Contas {
    private Conta contaRed = new Conta();
    private Conta contaGreen = new Conta();
}
```

In your rest session, inject `Contas`

```
@Inject
private Contas contas;
```

and access those like:

```
contas.getContaRed().whatever();
```

Since `Contas` is application scoped, `getContaRed|Green()` will return you the same red|green counter, those are not initialized again when `Contas` is injected elsewhere.

Comment: I'm studying Java EE 7.
Generally, which solution is preferred.
When I have to use multiple different instances of the same object (with Application or Session scope), how do I set it up?
A good practice to keep

Comment: There is no brief answer. But based on your question, it is a matter of an opinion but mostly of the case you need to solve. Qualifier is used when you need to decide what object (or a class representing the object) to instantiate: so if you have multiple implementations for some class / interface available. But when when you **instantiate** a class you need to think if you can just do `new Xyz()` or if you need to @Inject it.

Comment: The latter applies if the object needs to be instantiated with managed resources which in this case is not true. But you cannot declare some bean @Application scoped and expect it to be different instance in each injection: that is the whole point: it is application scoped. But it has been a while since EE for me. Mostly Spring so you should test my solution anyway I had no opportunity for testing just now.